# (JavaFX) How to pass instance of class to an FXML controller without knowing that controller's name?

Tags: java, javafx, fxml

I am developing a JavaFX application that has several "child" FXML views. I am struggling to make sure all the children have access to the "root" layout.

Here is the basic hierarchy of my application:

```
RootLayout
  -> SubLayout1
    -> UnknownLayout
```

`SubLayout1` is created from an FXML file when a button is clicked on the `RootLayout`.

Within the `SubLayout1` controller, I have code that will instantiate and load the `UnknownLayout` (FXML) and `UnknownLayoutController` (associated controller) files dynamically:

```
FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource(file.toString()));
loader.setController(controller);
loader.setRoot(this);
loader.load();
```

Both `file` and `controller` are assigned just prior to the FXML loading being done.

Since I am doing this dynamically, I do not know what the actual name of `UnknownLayout` or its controller will be.

My issue is that I can't figure out how to pass an instance of the `RootLayout` controller to the `UnknownLayoutController` so it can access the methods within that controller.  I do have a method in each `UnknownLayoutController` class that will allow me to pass the controller of `RootLayout` to it:

```
public void setRootLayoutController (RootLayoutController rootController) {}
```

Passing the `RootController` to `SubLayout1` isn't an issue because I can pass it with the constructor. But without knowing the actual name of `UnknownLayout`, how would I ever call that method?  Is there a way to call the new controller's constructor from within the `FXMLLoader` block?  Any "best practice" way to accomplish this?

My `controller` reference is created here:

```
StringBuilder controller = new StringBuilder();
controller.append(title + "Controller.java");
```

Thank you in advance for any help you can provide!

EDIT: I have tried several other suggestions to accomplish this, including [Passing Parameters JavaFX FXML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14187963/passing-parameters-javafx-fxml), but everything I've found assumes I know the name of the new controller prior to runtime.

I also looked into implementing an interface in `UnknownLayoutController`, but I then get a NullPointerException error on this code:

```
UnknownLayoutInterface subController = loader.getController();
subController.setRootController(rootController);
```

The `controller` variable is a String that **does** hold the name of the controller in question, but is there even a way to convert the String to an Object of the same name and access it that way?

(I am now defining the FXMLs controller in the FXML `fx:controller` tag instead of within the code).

Comment: *Is there a way to call the new controller's constructor from within the FXMLLoader block?* Could you clarify this? How do you create the controller? Using `fx:controller` in the fxml? Using the factory/strategy/command pattern?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve the situation by simplifying my code and determining the class type based on the filename (which was dynamically determined):

```
Class subLayout;
  SubLayout2Interface subInterface = null;
  try {
    subLayout = Class.forName([Full Package Name] + subLayoutTitle);
    subInterface = (SubLayout2Interface) subLayout.newInstance();
  } catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

subInterface.setRootController(this);
```